# How to get the numeric value of the below column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to get the value `71` out of the below `sdescription` column whose value is:

```
'€22.95 FUP BB charge for Black Waste: Total Weight: 71Kg'
```

Here is the code I used:

```
Select
  th.sDescription,
  right(sDescription,6) as [column1]
from TransactionHistory th
join #2050FUPBB t on t.cust = th.scustomerid
where dttimestamp between '31-July 2020 00:00' and '31-Jul-2020 23:29'
and sdescription like '%€22.95 FUP BB charge for Black Waste:%'
```

but I only get the result : `': 71Kg'`

Can you please help me get the value `'71'` if possible

Comment: You are getting the right 6 characters but the string you want is only 2 characters long.

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the database you are using as a tag to the question.

Comment: left(right(sDescription,4),2)

Comment: How large can the weight be? What if it were 12234 Kg - then 6 chars woldn't be enough. Are the units always Kg? If there are more than 999 units of weight, will the value be formatted with grouped digits, eg `12,345`? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi Guys , i am want to remove the KG and just get the value to the right of the sdescription

Comment: this is likely a regex expression to find that kind of value in strings - or you could use a substr( and instr combo to begin searching at the ':'

Comment: What happen with just simple `REPLACE(your_string, 'KG', '')`???

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
  th.sDescription,
  SUBSTRING(sDescription, CHARINDEX(':', sDescription)+1, 2)
from TransactionHistory th
join #2050FUPBB t on t.cust = th.scustomerid
where dttimestamp between '31-July 2020 00:00' and '31-Jul-2020 23:29'
and sdescription like '%€22.95 FUP BB charge for Black Waste:%'
```

Comment: What about the colon?

Comment: @Abion47 What if the weight is a longer number of digits?

Comment: yes and the units etc.. but answered the question asked..

Comment: @Bohemian Then this solution would need an overhaul in general, but it needed the edit to work at minimum.

Comment: @randy when i use your answer i get the below error
'The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s)'

Comment: @DavyStapleton - i used an oracle syntax... which RDBMS are you using? https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php

Comment: @randy I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: ok - of course that is a different syntax :) - i updated your question to be sql-server tagged.  i'll edit this answer with another variant.

Comment: @DavyStapleton - ok i edited for some substring manipulation - that should get you on the right track - this still only deals with 2 digit numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
replace(right(txt,len(txt)-charindex('Weight:',txt)-7),'Kg','')
```

This should handle weight of any length

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cebce64885a65193517efb98e08aa8c)

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace to remove unwanted text

```
Select
  th.sDescription,
  Replace(Replace(right(sDescription,6),'kg',''),':','') as [column1]
from TransactionHistory th
join #2050FUPBB t on t.cust = th.scustomerid
where dttimestamp between '31-July 2020 00:00' and '31-Jul-2020 23:29'
and sdescription like '%€22.95 FUP BB charge for Black Waste:%'
```